# histogram displays incorrectly in Streamlit

Tags: python, histogram, streamlit

---

Hi,
this is my streamlit code

```
import streamlit as st
import cv2

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 
img = cv2.imread('aa.jpg', -1)
st.image(img)
color = ('b','g','r')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.title('Histogram for color scale picture')
st.bar_chart(histr,use_container_width=True)
```

it displays this on the web page:
[image]

while it should be displaying this (without the streamlit use):
the code:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('aa.jpg', -1)
cv2.imshow('aa',img)
color = ('b','g','r')
for channel,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[channel],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.title('Histogram for color scale picture')
plt.show()
```

[image]

what can I do to fix this problem?
thank you in advance

Comment: With `plt.show()` the chart will always be displayed in a different window.
You should use `st.plotly_chart(histr)`.

Comment: it doesn's seem to work, i get this error  :
raise exceptions.PlotlyError(
_plotly_utils.exceptions.PlotlyError: The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing

```
st.bar_chart(histr,use_container_width=True)
```

with:

```
plt.savefig('hist.png')
hist=Image.open('hist.png')
st.image(hist)
```

and it appeats as I want on my page:
[image]